# Synchronising data in C#

Tags: c#

We use a third party dll which has an object called CServer and was provided by one of our software vendors to act as an API between our applications and their applications.

CServer has the following method:

`bool SynchroniseData()` which can be called if we want to fetch data from server which is very important for our application. This call signifies to the DLL our **intention** that we want to fetch the data. It does not fetch the data. Instead it returns true, if the request was successfully send to their application.

When data are actually fetched in the `CServer` object, `CServer` fires the event `onDataFetched`. We listen to that event and process the data. The `CServer` always has the latest data, since it continuously synchronises the data with our Vendor's servers.

However, there are many times at which the event `onDataSynchronisationStopped` is called. This signifies that the `CServer` object will stop data synchronisation with the server. This event is fired when the network is momentarily down, or if the server has some minor delays and so on.

We always want to have that data, and thus we try to fetch them again.

We currently do it like this:

```
private void OnDataFetchedHandler(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs){

            try{
                bool dataHaveBeenFetched;
                do{
                    dataHaveBeenFetched = TrytoFetchData((CServer) sender);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                } while (!dataHaveBeenFetched);
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                Log.ErrorFormat(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }

        private bool TrytoFetchData(CServer sender){
            sender.SynchroniseData();
            ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            EventHandler manualResetEventSethandler = (s, e) => manualResetEvent.Set();
            sender.OnDataFetched += manualResetEventSethandler;

            bool dataHaveBeenFetched = manualResetEvent.WaitOne(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3, 0));
            sender.OnDataFetched -= manualResetEventSethandler;

            return dataHaveBeenFetched;
        }
```

Is there any cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Why does the loop in the event handler has to wait 1 second? What for? Shouldn't the event be fired everytime data arrives? Mhmm this is a weird...

Comment: Is your intention for this code to continually execute? Each time `OnDataFetchedHandler()` calls `TrytoFetchData()`, another `CServer.OnDataFetched` is raised causing `OnDataFetchedHandler()` to fire again.

Comment: @t3chb0t, you are right, I have edited the code. The handler is the onDataSynchronisationStoppedHandler and not the onDataFetchedHandler.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Mast I had a copy paste mistake which was identified by the community. That's why I pasted the correct method name, and updated the community about the edit.

Comment: And had you made the edit before there was an answer, that would have been absolutely fine. But we take answer invalidation quite seriously, so we can't have you changing the code after there have been remarks about it in existing answers.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `do ... while` loop you can use [`SpinWait.SpinUntil`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.spinwait.spinuntil?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_SpinWait_SpinUntil_System_Func_System_Boolean__System_TimeSpan_):

```
bool dataHaveBeenFetched = SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => TrytoFetchData((CServer)sender))
```

And as [@t3chb0t](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/59161/t3chb0t) noted it seems strange to sleep 1 second between `TrytoFetchData` calls.